# Importing Python with extensions in C++

Tags: c++, python, linux

SOLVED: turns out I had a messed up path var in link script

I have a problem concerning executing embedded python code in C++. I have a C++ program that dynamically executes a regular Python file using:

```
...
PyObject_CallObject(func, args);
...
```

Everything works as expected when I use plain function in the injected python scripts. But when I want to import some extension in the python script:

```
import "libraryname"
...
```

, I get the following runtime error:

> ImportError: No module named "libraryname"
>   ...

The python code works using the regular interpreter but not ones it's injected in C++. I've tried explicitly loading the python library folder both in the PATH var and in the linker without any success.

(I'm using Linux/Debian.)

Answer (score 4):

Imports in Python don't use quotes around the name.

```
import libraryname
```

Also, inject the module into `sys.modules` first.